# I want to add a video in my HTML code

Tags: html, video

I'm here to ask you why I can't see my video on my website. I just can see the buttons ( play / pause .. ) but I can't push them. I want to know what's the problem and what can I do to solve this problem ?

Please Help me please

```
<div class="row">
    <section class="slide slide-one go panel" id="one" data-background="#c99b60">
            <div class="col-md-9 video">
              <video src="vd/1.mov" autoplay controls></video>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 medium-size">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h1 class="etape">Étape 1</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      <img class="ima" src="img/logob.svg" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <hr>
              <h1 class="title-custom"></h1>
              <p>Prenez un grand récipient , versez y un verre de sirop de cannes. Ajoutez-y ensuite un verre d’eau.</p>
            </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

.mov is not a supported video format. You should use .mp4, .webm or .ogg. i suggest you use .mp4 because it is supported by all popular browsers (the other 2 are not supported by the safari browser)

Comment: it should something like this

<video width="320" height="240" autoplay controls>
  <source src="vd/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>